# Summarise which fields contain data for a given Solr query

Tags: solr

This is best asked using an example.

An electronics store's Solr index has documents for cameras, printers, routers, phones, etc.  There are fields which are present in some docs, and absent in others. For example printers generally have a dpi_i field, cameras might have a sensor_size_f and megapixels_i field, and so on.

Is there a way to get a summary of the presence/absence of data in **all** fields based on the results of a given query?  Something like faceting on all fields, paying special attention to the number of missing values?

So when you search for "Epson", the result would tell you that the dpi_i field was highly populated (maybe 90%, I'm guessing) and the sensor_size_f and megapixels_i fields would be 0% populated (at least with current products - looks like they used to make a nice rangefinder camera 10 years ago...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it I'd say you want to use the stats component (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component).

Just add `stats=true&stats.field=dpi_i&stats.field=sensor_size_f` (and so on) and you should be good to go. Just calculate the `missing` / `count` fields.